# Class Design Needed

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have two classes, class A and class B.
class A has a method which creates an instance of class B and calls a public method using that instance.

```
B obj = new B();
obj.DoSomething();
```

Now DoSomething() method of class B has a loop.

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
    {
       //Do some task
       //call a method of class A for this iteration
    }
}
```

What is the best way to do this?
If I create an instance of class A in DoSomething() method and then call the method of class A, will it lead to circular reference? Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: Why not pass in your original instance of `A` as an argument to the `DoSomething` method? EDIT: Also, hard to say based on the limited context, but another possibility is to require the `B` constructor to be supplied with an instance of `A`, and `B` can store that reference in a private field.

Comment: Is it ((passing an instance to a method or constructor of another class) the right way to do this?

Comment: Hard to say based on the limited context but this behavior in coupled classes should indicate bad architecture design. If responsabilities are well designed B should not rely on superior layer to work properly.

Comment: @TheKing, can you give us a little more context? What do classes A and B do? What does `DoSomething` do? Passing an instance of A to the method/constructor of B would indeed solve the problem, but like @jvaquero said, you might just be masking a design flaw.

Comment: @jlvaquero, may be this is a bad architecture design. How can this be corrected?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that it's not clear if `A` is a dependency of `B` or `B` is a dependency of `A`. First of all, I think you have to define this aspect. With this clear in mind your classes design will be more natural and fluent.

So, for example, if you need to `DoSomething()` in `B` using an `A` instance, you could put an `A` member in your `B` class:

```
public class B
{
    private A _aInstance;

    public B(A aInstance)
    {
        this._aInstance = aInstance;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
        {
           //Do some task
           _aInstance.DoSomethingOther();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your program logic you can either pass through the reference to the current instance of class A using `this` keyword.

Or change the program logic such that the loop is in class A. The loop will then call the methods in class B; After which the calling method in class A calls the appropriate method for the iteration.